# L1-norm of a stable, proper but not strictly proper transfer function

Tags: linear-systems, transfer-function, norm

in the literature I find the statement, that the L-norms exist for every strictly proper and stable transfer function. I ask myself, if the L1-norm also exists for a transfer function, that has as many poles as zeros (proper, but not strictly proper).

Take for example the transfer function $G(s) = \frac{s}{s+1}$, the corresponding impulse response is $g(t) = \delta(t) - e^{-t}$.

The L1 norm, if it exists, would then be equal to $\int_{0}^{\infty} | \delta(t) - e^{-t} | dt $. Matlab symbolic toolbox and Wolframalpha refuse to solve that integral.

By definition, the L1-norm upper-bounds the ratio between the L-infinity norms of output and input of an LTI system.

$ \|G(s)\|_{L1} \geq \frac{\|Y(s)\|_{L \infty}}{\|U(s)\|_{L \infty}} $

If our L1-norm here is not defined, would that mean, that there cannot be found such an upper bound? That would in my opinion then mean, that an input signal with e.g. the L-infinity norm 1 could excite such a (stable!) system to any arbitrarily high absolute value on the output for at least a short time, which seems odd to me.

That there is no definition of the L1 norm could on the other hand just mean, that the upper bound cannot be calculated by that approach. How can it then be calculated?

If you omit the absolute value function, the integral seems to exist.

For $\int_{0}^{\infty}  \delta(t) - e^{-t}  dt $, Matlab symbolic toolbox calculates it to -1/2, but Wolframalpha says it's -Heaviside(0), which is -1, according to Wolframalpha itself. Now I'm confused.

Type for Matlab:
syms t; int(dirac(t) - exp(-t), t, 0, inf)

Type for Wolframalpha:
int(dirac(t)-exp(-t), 0 to inf)

If the integral of the argument exists, why shouldn't the integral of the absolute value exist as well?

I'm not a mathematician and very curious on any clarification. Thank you.

Paul

Comment: Matlab and Wolfram Alpha are not the only ones unable to solve that integral: It does not exist. For any $\varepsilon>0$, $$\int_{0}^{\infty} | \delta(t) - e^{-t} |\, \mathrm dt > \int_{\varepsilon}^{\infty} | \delta(t) - e^{-t} |\,\mathrm dt = \int_{\varepsilon}^{\infty} | 0 - e^{-t} |\,\mathrm dt = \int_{\varepsilon}^{\infty} e^{-t}\,\mathrm dt = \left[- \frac 1t e^{-t} \right]_{t=\varepsilon}^{t=\infty}.$$  And $$\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac1t e^{-t}$$ diverges, because "$\frac10$" diverges.

Comment: No, I think that is not correct.

$ \int e^{-t} dt = -e^{-t} + c $

At least in that term, nothing should diverge, when taking a definite integral from zero to infinity.

Comment: oops, you're right, my mental antiderivatve was wrong. Well, anyway, then you can actually solve this integral using my method above (split the integral into a piece from epsilon to infty, and from 0 to epsilon)

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice approach. That would mean, that the norm exists, and that the L-infinity ratio is in fact upper bounded.

It's still a bit strange, that in the literature, this existence is not mentioned. Maybe because of this difficulty in the numerical calculation. Matlab and Wolframalpha are contradictory here, as said above. I'm rather on the side of Matlab.